# Remove duplicated records keeping last usign ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been trying to remove the records that are duplicated (same value in the column `shopify_order_id`) keeping the most recent one.

I wrote it in sql:

```
select orders.id from (
  select shopify_order_id, min(shopify_created_at) as min_created 
  from orders group by shopify_order_id having count(*) > 1 limit 5000
) as keep_orders 
join orders 
on 
  keep_orders.shopify_order_id = orders.shopify_order_id and 
  orders.shopify_created_at <> keep_orders.min_created
```

and now I'm trying to get it to Active Record but can't seem to join the two parts.

The first nested select is

```
Order.select('shopify_order_id, MIN(shopify_created_at) as min_created').
        group(:shopify_order_id).
        having('count(*) > 1').
        limit(5000)
```

but then the following doesn't work:

```
Order.select('orders.id').from(keep_orders, :keep_orders).
joins('orders ON keep_orders.shopify_order_id = orders.shopify_order_id').
where.not('orders.shopify_created_at = keep_orders.min_created')
```

it builds the query:

```
SELECT  orders.id FROM  (SELECT  shopify_order_id, MIN(shopify_created_at) as min_created FROM "orders" GROUP BY "orders"."shopify_order_id" HAVING (count(*) > 1) LIMIT $1) keep_orders  orders ON keep_orders.shopify_order_id = orders.shopify_order_id WHERE NOT (orders.shopify_created_at = keep_orders.min_created) ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["LIMIT", 5000], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

which is missing the keyword `join`.

Any help on how to refactor the query/do it in another way would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `joins` with a [string SQL fragment](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment) you need to specify the type of join you want:

```rb
Order.select('orders.id').from(keep_orders, :keep_orders)
  .joins('JOIN orders ON keep_orders.shopify_order_id = orders.shopify_order_id')
  .where.not('orders.shopify_created_at = keep_orders.min_created')
```